# When new-able use new T(), otherwise use default(T)

Tags: c#, generics, types, default

I am working on a C# generic function. When error, if the generic type can be new-able, return `new T()`, otherwise return `default(T)`.

The code like this:

```
private T Func<T>()
{
    try
    {
        // try to do something...
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (T is new-able) // <---------- How to do this?
        {
            return new T();
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it needs `where T : new()` for those using `new T()`. This question is, how to judge this on runtime?

Comment: Although achievable using reflection, this indicates a rather smelly convention for callers of that method IMHO. Can you describe a bit better what exactly is that you're trying to do?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken can you not just use `return Activator.CreateInstance(T)`?

Comment: @Sayse No, that will throw exception if no parameterless constructor defined.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Judging by the OP's example, I presumed that would be fine, but thanks

Comment: This seems like a really bad design. Even then, your code doesn't seem to implement your design goals: you seem to want to absolutely never let any thrown exception be visible outside of your function. But what if `new T()` throws?

Comment: @hvd The basic idea is to avoid try-catch boilerplate in caller function. If return `default(T)` when `T` a list, it is not safe to chain in the caller. For those `T` is a list or my model, I can assert it's safe to do `new T()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to check whether the type has a parameterless constructor. You do it by calling`Type.GetConstructor` method with empty types as parameter.

```
var constructorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
if(constructorInfo != null)
{
   //here you go
   object instance = constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In *here you go* section, how can I use `constructorInfo ` to new instance?

Comment: @LiJunLe Updated my answer, You'll have to call `constructorInfo.Invoke`

Comment: Rollbacked the edit: `GetConstructor` method returns only public constructor if you don't specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic`; so checking for `constructorInfo.IsPublic` is redundant.

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly, `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` will return an object constructed with the parameterless constructor if `T` is a class or a `default(T)` if `T` is a struct.

You can use the technique in Sriram's answer to first make sure a parameterless constructor exists for `T`.

Comment: If no parameterless constructor, it will throw exception. Isn't it?

Comment: in that case you can still catch the exception and return default(T)... not perfectly performant but otherwise ok.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit - Exceptions should be there to catch the exceptional, not for program flow

Comment: @Sayse well i agree in general but not necessarily for this specific example. I think it's ok to define such rules in your team / company, but postulating this as a "hard rule" without explaining it in detail is basically falling back to a (kind of fanatic) behavior which was somewhat obsolete since the age of enlightment. As for the topic at hand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control contains quite some information.

Answer (score 1):

You could something like checking for a default constructor and execute new T() if one is found. 
To do this you could use something like:

```
var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
if(constructor != null)
{
    return (T)constructor.Invoke(null);
}
else
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: `new T();` won't compile. Because there is no `new()` constraint defined.

Comment: oh yes...you're right. Did not realize that. There would be no need to check for the default constructor if the constraint would be in place

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I cannot use `new T()` here. Because that must declare `where T : new()` which I should avoid.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to @SriramSakthivel

Answer (score 1):

I little played with [MarcoLaser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782739/marcolaser)'s answer and made my
'**if T is newable then get instance constructor**'

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
        public MyClass()
        {
            var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            if (constructor != null)
                Data = (T)constructor.Invoke(null);  
        }

        public T Data { get; set; }
}
```