# When T is collection, how to return of type collection. Currently it returns null

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, collections, task

When T is collection, how to return of  type collection. Currently it returns null

```
public static async Task<T> CallWebApi<T>(string url, string accessToken)
{
      T result = default(T);
      var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
      {
            return result; // returns null now. When T is collection, we want to return of   
                           // type collection
      }
}
```

Comment: You need to get the response's Content. That's your desired data.

Comment: Also, you want it if StatusCode is not NotFound

Comment: Have a look at the example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#examples

Comment: As I understand, OP wants to return empty collection when status code is not found, IF T is "collection" type (IEnumerable?). And now it returns null (because `default(T)` is null).

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197482/when-new-able-use-new-t-otherwise-use-defaultt.

Comment: Just return `null` and at the call site do `var loaded = CallWebApi<List<int>>() ?? new List<int>()`.

Comment: What happens when `response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound`? You haven't shown us what the `CallWebApi` returns in this case (the normal case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to provide a good default value for any possible `T`. It's also obscure to the caller of the function what that default value might be.

A good pattern is thus to have the caller of the function provide that default value himself. That way the function can be used with any type `T` without guessing what would be a good default value for any possible `T`, and without causing surprises to callers.

```cs
public static async Task<T> CallWebApi<T>(string url, string accessToken, T defaultValue)
{
      var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
      {
            return defaultValue;
      }
      // else
      //   get the content and deserialize to T, 
      //   throw an exception if that doesn't work
}
```

The caller can then use it like:

```cs
var result = await CallWebApi<Model[]>(url, accessToken, Array.Empty<Model>());
```

Arguably, this is still all too complicated. What if the API returns an empty array? How would you know if that empty array is a default value or the actual API response?

With nullable reference types, a type-safe pattern that doesn't lose information that way is simply:

```cs
public static async Task<T?> CallWebApi<T>(string url, string accessToken) where T: class 
{
      var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
      {
            return null;
      }
}
```

And callers cannot treat `T?` as a value of `T` without first checking if it's not null, which means they won't accidentally run into `NullReferenceException`s or other such design problems.

Comment: Task<T?> does not supports in c# 7.3 version which we are using currently. Nullable reference types not supported in this version.

Comment: Then perhaps the default value is the way to go, or you could look into using an Option/Either type as an alternative to nullable reference types (e.g. return Option.None instead of null).

Comment: I prefer to go with `default value`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would provide default value factory parameter:

```cs
static async Task<T> CallWebApi<T>(string url, string accessToken, Func<T> defaultFactory = default)
{
    var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        return defaultFactory is null
            ? default
            : defaultFactory();
    }

    return default;
}
```

Or just default value itself:

```cs
static async Task<T> CallWebApi<T>(string url, string accessToken, T defaultValue = default)
{
   ...
}
```

And let user write a little bit more wordy but clear code.

Otherwise you can try checking if type implements `IEnumerable` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864630/2501279)) and if it has parameterless ctor ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25197525/2501279)) and exclude some "corner cases" like `string` (which is `IEnumerable<char>`) and decide what to do with collection interfaces (like `IList<T>` - here you will need to decide what base collection would and make some reflection generic magic via `Type.MakeGenericType()`).